Configure binance nodejs for binance tr api
I want to use binance tr api ; so i want to configure https://github.com/tiagosiebler/binance
this for binance tr api.
I changed  links but not work.
Like this ( in binance/src/util
/requestUtils.ts) :
const BINANCE_BASE_URLS: Record<BinanceBaseUrlKey, string> = {
  // spot/margin/savings/mining
  **spot: 'https://www.binance.tr',//i configure this area**
  spot1: 'https://api.binance.com',
  spot2: 'https://api1.binance.com',
  spot3: 'https://api2.binance.com',
  spot4: 'https://api3.binance.com',

  // USDM Futures
  usdm: 'https://fapi.binance.com',
  usdmtest: 'https://testnet.binancefuture.com',

  // COINM Futures
  coinm: 'https://dapi.binance.com',
  coinmtest: 'https://testnet.binancefuture.com',

  // Vanilla Options
  voptions: 'https://vapi.binance.com',
  voptionstest: 'https://testnet.binanceops.com',
};

This is the binance tr doc : https://www.binance.tr/apidocs/#change-log
